# Comment utiliser venez-vous + infinitif

Tags: impératif

Est-ce qu'il est possible de former un impératif avec venez-vous + infinitif?

Dans mon cours de yoga j'entends souvent "Tournez complètement sur le côté droit et venez-vous asseoir en tailleur." ou "Venez dérouler votre colonne vertébrale"

Est-ce qu venir fonctionne comme un impératif dans ces phrases? Est-ce que vous pouvez me donner d'autres exemples pour utiliser cette structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Venez* **est** un impératif dans :

> Venez vous asseoir en tailleur.

Au singulier:

> Viens t'asseoir...

*Vous* est ici le pronom réfléchi du verbe *s’asseoir* (forme pronominale).

Il n'y a donc pas de tiret entre *venez* et *vous* car un tiret indiquerait une question avec inversion verbe-sujet comme dans:

> Venez-vous dîner chez nous demain ?

voire même :

> Venez-vous vous asseoir en tailleur ?

On aurait pu utiliser le verbe s’asseoir à l'impératif :

> Venez (ici) et asseyez-vous en tailleur.

Comment: Ce n'est pas le même 'vous', en fait. À une personne familière, on dira "Quand viens-tu t'asseoir ?" (contraction de "te asseoir").